# PHP how to remove remove \n\n from php mail body

Tags: php, email

When I send mail from php and the type message in ckeditor textarea, I get mail like below:

[image]

**I want to remove \n\n**

Thanks in advance.

Here my code

```
<?php
$to = $resrow['recevie_email'];
$subject = $esub;
$message = "Hi Admin,<br>";
$message .= "<br/><br/>";
$message .= "There is a query from user described below.<br>";
$message .= "Name : ".$_SESSION['first_name'] ." ".$_SESSION['last_name'];
$message .= "<br/>";
$message .= "ROLE : ".$mail_from;
$message .= "<br/>";
$message .= "Email : ".$_SESSION['EMAIL'];
$message .= "<br/>";
$message .= "Phone : ".$userdetail['phone'];
$message .= "<br/>";
$message .= "Query : ".$data;
$message .= "<br><br>";
$message .= "Please contact ".$mail_from." on above details to resolve the query.";
$message .= "<br><br>";
$message .= "Thank you,<br>";
$message .= "Elevon Team.";

$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'From: Elevon <'.$resrow['send_email'].'>';

$message = trim($message, "\n");

$mail_conf = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

?>
```

Comment: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Where is your code?

Comment: Hi @NikitaAgrawal here my code is as 

        $mail->setFrom('info@localhost.com','Localhost');

        $mail->addAddress($email);   // Add a recipient

        $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        
        $data = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $data));
        
        $mail->Body    = $data;

Comment: @Rahul Edit your Question and post the Code there

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal i edited my question above and add my code , review once

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here i found the answer, to remove \n\n from mail message body we have to just use str_replace as below

$data = str_replace('\n',' ',$data);

Here the full code

```
<?php
$data = str_replace('\n',' ',$data);

$to = $resrow['recevie_email'];
$subject = $esub;
$message = "Hi Admin,<br>";
$message .= "<br/><br/>";
$message .= "There is a query from user described below.<br>";
$message .= "Name : ".$_SESSION['first_name'] ." ".$_SESSION['last_name'];
$message .= "<br/>";
$message .= "ROLE : ".$mail_from;
$message .= "<br/>";
$message .= "Email : ".$_SESSION['EMAIL'];
$message .= "<br/>";
$message .= "Phone : ".$userdetail['phone'];
$message .= "<br/>";
$message .= "Query : ".$data;
$message .= "<br><br>";
$message .= "Please contact ".$mail_from." on above details to resolve the query.";
$message .= "<br><br>";
$message .= "Thank you,<br>";
$message .= "Elevon Team.";

$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'From: Elevon <'.$resrow['send_email'].'>';

$message = trim($message, "\n");

$mail_conf = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

?>
```